# How can I separate CSS of two separate components in Angular 2?

Tags: html, css, angular, angularjs-directive, angular-cli

In Component 1

CSS--

```
ngx-dnd-container {
    color:black;
    background-color: white;
}
```

HTML-

```
<ngx-dnd-container
            [model]="targetItemsA"
            dropZone="multiple-target-a"
          </ngx-dnd-container>
```

In Component 2

CSS--

```
ngx-dnd-container {
    color:white;
    background-color: orange;
}

<ngx-dnd-container
            [model]="targetItemsA"
            dropZone="multiple-target-a"
          </ngx-dnd-container>
```

Whenever I run my project in both component's html it is showing CSS of First Component. Please He

Comment: You can put the css file paths in the `styleUrls` metadata under the `@Component()` decorator

Comment: I have already done that. Still it is taking the first css value for both components.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: Nope. Problem still exists in my code.

Comment: Can you MP me a link to see the source code to help me identify your problem ? Component CSS boxing can be changed, but it should be changed within the @Component annotation. Maybe you did something somewhere that changed the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

When defining an Angular Component, you can specify CSS stylesheets that will be used only by the Component, like so:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['my.component.scss']  // <-- Here
})
export class MyComponent {
  // Component code
}
```

Take note that the value is an Array and that it can thus take several file paths.

Comment: I have already done that. Still it is taking the first css value for both components.

Comment: It shouldn't be the case. You're not including the stylesheets into any HTML, are you?

Comment: To be accurate, the only place in your code where the CSS filename should appear is in the styleUrls array.

Comment: I have already done that. Still it is taking the first css value for both components.

Comment: There is something wrong somewhere in your project then, this is not a normal behavior. I would recommend reviewing your entire code with an experimented dev.